# Nginx Exclude a query string url from being redirected

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am currently redirecting my root domain to a subfolder. However I want to exclude a query string url which is used for an ajax call (www.example.com/?act=12). I am however unsure of how to do this in nginx.

This is my current nginx config file

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     example.com;
        return 301      http://www.example.com$request_uri;

}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        root /var/www/example.com/public;

        index index.php index.html;

        location = / {
                return 301 http://www.example.com/it/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
                expires 30d;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be achieved by using the [evil if](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) block.

The query string arguments are presented as variables with a `$arg_` prefix. If you just need to test that `act` is set, try this:

```
location = / {
    if ($arg_act) {
        rewrite ^ /my/ajax/call last;
    }
    return 301 http://www.example.com/it/;
}
```

If you need to test for a specific value of `$arg_act` use the `=` operator.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for details.